# How do I allow pinned sites to use cookies to generate the website thumbnail?

Tags: firefox

I'm pinning a lot of websites that require cookies in some way. Without cookies, the thumbnails mostly show login screens and cookie walls. Is there a way to tell Firefox that it can use cookies for the top/pinned sites thumbnails?

I don't mind hacks or fiddling with about:config.

[image: demo]

Comment: Most websites that use cookies for authentication expire the cookies after a set time for security reasons. The format and content of cookies is not standard.

Comment: Due to the consistency of the issue, this is unlikely to be related to expiration. It is probably a security or privacy measure by Firefox that may or may not be configurable somehow.

Comment: That is a fair point. I wonder if they are just pre-rendered snapshots or if the browser makes a request each time.

Comment: According to [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thumbnails-new-tab-page-missing-how-get-them-back) KB article they are snapshotted the first time you go to the website. You would have to probably write a plugin to get the behaviour you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been browsing the source.

[This is the place where the browser that will capture the thumbnails is configured](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/6c7c983bce46a460c2766fbdd73283f6d2b03a69/toolkit/components/thumbnails/content/backgroundPageThumbsContent.js):

```js
priority = Ci.nsISupportsPriority.PRIORITY_LOWEST;

docShell.allowMedia = false;
docShell.allowPlugins = false;
docShell.allowContentRetargeting = false;
let defaultFlags = Ci.nsIRequest.LOAD_ANONYMOUS |
                   Ci.nsIRequest.LOAD_BYPASS_CACHE |
                   Ci.nsIRequest.INHIBIT_CACHING |
                   Ci.nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_BYPASS_HISTORY;
```

There's no plugin hook or infrastructure to extend these `defaultFlags`.